# Prototypal inheritance in JS and how to get parent properties

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototype-programming, prototypal-inheritance

I'm trying to have properties inherit from a parent, but I'm not clear as to the right way of doing it.

Lets say I have:

```
var Animal = function(name){
  this.offspring = [];
  this.name = name;
  return this;
}

Animal.prototype.createOffspring = function(name){
  name = name || 'Baby '+(this.offspring.length+1);
  this.offspring.push(name);
  return this;
}
```

Now I want to add a sub prototype inherit so I don't have to manually add everything from the parent. For example, lets say I want to add a `Cat` based from `Animal`

I'd like to do this, like if it were an `Animal`

```
var pet = new Cat('Kitty');
pet.createOffspring();
```

Without manually having to add `name` and `createOffspring` to the Cat `constructor` which is really just an `Animal`, but with some other added functionality (like `.meow()` or something).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// Parent
function Animal() {
  this.name = 'An animal';
}

// Some child
function Cat() {
  this.speaks = 'Meow'; 
}
// Here comes inheritence
Cat.prototype = new Animal();
// Or like that
// but don't forget to put all inheritable fields to Animal's prototype
Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype); 

// Let 'instanceof' work. Don't forget the following line, 
// because we eraese the info about constructor of Cat instances.
Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;
// Add some custom method
Cat.prototype.meow = function() { return this.speaks; }

var cat = new Cat();
var animal = new Animal();

/// Some tests
cat.name; // A animal
animal.name; // An animal
cat.meow(); // Meow!
cat instanceof Cat; // true
cat instanceof Animal; // true
```

That's it?
(UPD: Error with prototype fixed)
(UPD2: Sorry. It is late night, I make a lot of mistakes.. I must go sleep)

---

There is also another solution, but its Chrome,FF-specific (maybe others):

```
// Animal and Cat functions from above, but
Cat.prototype = {
  __proto__: Animal.prototype,
  constructor: Cat,
  meow: function() { ... }
}
```

Looks shorter, but not'd be tempted by this: it's better to follow ECMAScript standart.

Comment: I need to test it, but i'd like to _not_ have to redo `this.name` because _all_ animals will have a name therefore, `this.name = 'A cat';` should be able to be removed and `cat.name` should return `An animal`

Comment: Oh, sorry. I mislead you to wrong answer: Animal.prototype was not setup, so `cat.name` would give an exception. The right way, when instance is constructed dynamicaly, is to assign an object to a proto: `Cat.prototype = Object.create(new Animal())`

Comment: This got me in the right direction and thank you very much. Sorry it took so long :) 

The only things that seem to be strange are that `Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;` in or not in the code works the same and I still get `true` on the `instanceof`s. Also the `Object.create()` line makes `cat.name` undefined.

http://jsbin.com/uhogig/edit#javascript,html

Comment: To get line with `Object.create` working you should put `name` field into `Animal.prototype` first (see the the previous line w/comment before creation). So it will not work when name is declared in constructor only.

What about `Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;`... It was hard for me to remember that but try this code `(new Cat()).constructor.name` (i get "Animal"). Once my code relied on ctor-s names so I put that line here habitually :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different patterns for implementing inheritance like you're describing in JavaScript, and they have subtle differences as far as how they treat the prototype objects.

Here's are a couple of good references on the [prototype pattern](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#prototypepatternjavascript) and the [constructor pattern](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#constructorpatternjavascript) to get you started.

And here's a [simple implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/joshearl/3ccPt/1/) of what you described.